# Facing issues in JavaScript "get" method deployed via netlify

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get, netlify

I made an real time chat application. Mysql database is used.
Code in my local system works perfectly, ie get method via
`http://localhost:3000/`.
It is not working in, while deploy in netlify.
I think it seems some internal routing issue.
Unfortunately I'am not paid member in netlify, so unable to find my application logs in netlify.
Is there any way to resolve this issue.
Although the home page `index.html`, this is displaying with netlify website link, unfortunately issue is with get and post method.
Please find my two files below.(`index.html` and `server.js`).
Along with this there is connection.js for database purpose (not included)
I changed this line in my code (local system to live server):
**local server**

```
$.get('http://localhost:3000/messages', (data) => {
```

with this

**live server**

```
$.get('https://repoName.netlify.app/messages', (data) => {
```

Appreciate if i get a chance to resolve this roadblock!
index.html

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1 class="display-4">Send Message</h1>
                <br>
                <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                <br>
                <textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
                <br>
                <button id="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
            </div>
            <div id="messages">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(() => {
                $("#send").click(() => {
                    sendMessage({
                        name: $("#name").val(),
                        message: $("#message").val()
                    });
                })
                getMessages()
            })
            function addMessages(message) {
                $("#messages").append(`
          <h4>${message.name} : </h4>
          <p>${message.message}</p>`)
            }
            function getMessages() {
                $.get('http://localhost:3000/messages', (data) => {
                    data.forEach(addMessages);
                })
            }
            function sendMessage(message) {
                $.post('http://localhost:3000/messages', message)
                getMessages()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

server.js

```js
    var express = require('express')
    var app = express()
    var db = require('./connection')
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    var cors = require('cors')
    app.use(express.static(__dirname))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    app.use(cors())
    // mysql
    function selectUser() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let sql = `Select * from user`
            db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err
                resolve(result)
            })
        })
    }
    let insertUser = (name, msg) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let sql = `INSERT INTO user (name, message) VALUES ('${name}','${msg}')`
            db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
                if (err) { reject(err) }
                resolve(result)
            })
        })
    }
    // routes
    app.get('/messages', async (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        let data
        await selectUser().then((response) => {
            JSON.stringify(response)
            data = response
        })
        res.send(data)
    })
    app.post('/messages', async (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        await insertUser(req.body.name, req.body.message).then(() => {
        }).catch(() => {
            res.sendStatus(500)
        })
        res.sendStatus(200)
    })
    // port
    var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Server is running on port', server.address().port);
    })
```

Comment: you need to change what port your app is runnning on to `https://repoName.netlify.app:3000/messages`

Comment: You haven’t described the problem, other than “not working”.  Are you getting errors in the browser console?

Comment: There no language named `java script` there is `java` or `javascript`. there is no hypothetical "scripting" language based on the java language

Comment: Thanks for your help @DeanVanGreunen.  `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` .this i am getting in browser logs as i did your suggestion `POST https://repoName.netlify.app:3000/messages net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: thanks james, and thanks @MisterJojo. I am getting in browser logs `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` while using this URL `$.get('https://repoName.netlify.app/messages', (data) => {` - @James

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing when deploying your real-time chat application on Netlify may be due to the fact that you are making AJAX requests to your server using the local development URL `(http://localhost:3000/messages)`. When you deploy your application to Netlify, you should use relative URLs or the correct product URL for your server.

Here's how you can modify your code to work both natively and when deployed to Netlify:

Update your JavaScript code in index.html to use relative URLs for your AJAX requests. Change this line:

```
$.get('http://localhost:3000/messages', (data) => {
```

with:

```
$.get('/messages', (data) => {
```

Similarly, update your $.post request in the same way:

```
$.post('/messages', message)
```

This change allows your application to make requests to the same domain it is hosted on, whether on your local server or on Netlify.

Make sure your server is configured to listen to the correct port when deployed to Netlify. In your server.js, you are currently using port 3000:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port', server.address().port);
})
```

In a production environment such as Netlify, the use of port 3000 is not feasible. Netlify dynamically assigns a port, and you should rely on the process.env.PORT variable to ascertain the correct port:

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port', server.address().port);
})
```

By implementing this adjustment, your server will listen on the port assigned by Netlify.

Following these updates, your application should function seamlessly both in local development and when deployed on Netlify, eliminating any routing problems. Be sure to adapt your server configuration when deploying to production environments.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation, really appreciate your effort @iDibya.com. I did the changes as per your suggestion. getting this in browser logs `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Comment: It happens for many reasons like wrong Netlify configuration or file is not present in the expected location on the server or Make sure your server is configured to allow cross-origin requests from your Netlify-hosted frontend or Make sure your server is properly configured to handle the routes you want to access